# 13.022698] nvidia-modeset: Version mismatch: nvidia.ko(430.64) nvidia-modeset.ko(460.32.03)

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, cuda

I have been trying to get cuda 10.2 installed on ubuntu 18.04. I am getting this mismatch error. There are similar posts on stackoverflow. I tried deleting dpkg lines, and repeat the install script, but they had no effect.

tried

```
sudo apt-get install libnvidia-compute-460=430.64
```

to match up the two, and get

```
E: Version '430.64' for 'libnvidia-compute-460' was not found
```

when I run

```
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.64.run --uninstall
```

I get

```
There is no NVIDIA driver currently installed.
```

what else should I try?

Answer (score 0):

solved by using the .run install script for nvidia instead of .deb